# ADT V22 properties Tab cannot input

Tags: android, adt

After update to ADT V22. I can not input anything on the Graphical Layout Mode, on the properties tab. The options part, I can click, it will show options, but after I click, it return nothing. this is new download, I only install SVN plug. Any help?

Here is the screen shot.
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/87922863/%E6%9C%AA%E5%91%BD%E5%90%8D.jpg
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/87922863/TM%E6%88%AA%E5%9B%BE20131119162939.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also had this problem. Just change API version from 19 to 18.

See your first screen at the left top corner